# Rails model multiple properties of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm struggle to find a way to have more than one property of the same model. I've this structure :

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :content_type
end

class MenuImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :image
   belongs_to :menu
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :menu_images
   has_many :images, :through => :menu_images

   has_one :image, :as => :thumbnail_image

   attr_accessible :thumbnail_image_id
end
```

I want to be able to access the images using `@menu.images` and `@menu.thumbnail_image`.
The code `has_one :image, :as => :thumbnail_image` is an example of what i'm trying to obtain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to use backticks (\`) to markup inline code in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You name it differently, but tell ActiveRecord to use the Image class:

```
has_one :thumbnail_image, :class_name => "Image"
```

See also the Association Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference

Comment: But the question was about the `Menu`, where it has to have `belongs_to` counterpart.

Comment: `belongs_to :thumbnail_image, :class_name => 'Image'` and now is working